# Enable WSS (secure websocket) on Windows DotNet application

Tags: .net, visual-studio, websocket, wss

I have a window dotnet application which is used a websocket server. We could connect to the websocket server using WS:// protocol. I want to enable WSS:// protocol as well.

I am aware that we need to create self signed certificate, but where to install and configure the certificate for my window app and how to enable SSL/TLS for a window app?

Could you please help how to enable WSS protocol. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

add this function to your code

```cs
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
                object sender,
                X509Certificate certificate,
                X509Chain chain,
                SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            {
                return true; 
            }
```

and call it once like this

```cs
RemoteCertificateValidationCallback remote = ValidateServerCertificate;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = remote;
```

on need for accepting the SSL certificate of the websocket the callback will be invoked and it will return true so you app will be fine.
please note that I have not tested on windows  application also supposing you have used [ClientWebSocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket?view=netframework-4.7.2)